# What is the equivalent of PowerShell Invoke-WebRequest in Java?

Tags: java, powershell, webrequest

I'm porting a PowerShell script to Java. One of the PowerShell commands is `Invoke-WebRequest` that looks like:

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest $formUrl -SessionVariable session1
```

I was wondering if anyone knew a quick way of doing this in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`Invoke-WebRequest` issues a HTTP request to the URL at `$formUrl` and stores the results in the `$r` variable. The `-SessionVariable` argument also stores state information, such as cookies and credentials in an object that can be shared with further requests. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx for a complete documentation on `Invoke-WebRequest`.

In Java, you can use `java.net.HttpURLConnection` / `java.net.URL` to issue a HTTP request and fetch the response. From what I gather, these are pretty-low level classes and you will have to do quite a bit of bookkeeping to provide the functionality of a PowerShell session variable. For instance, cookie management is provided by `java.net.CookieManager`, but credentials are handled a different way.

You may also want to look into Apache HttpComponents (formerly called Apache HttpClient) or other HTTP libraries for Java that take care of state management.